# 1000 Base-LX compatible with 100 Base-FX

Tags: cisco, fiber, sfp

I'm trying to connect a Cisco Catalyst 3750 12-port SFP switch to a RuggedCom RSG2100 with fiber ports.  The Cisco has a third-party SFP (GLC-LH-SM) that shows in "show interface" as 1000Base-LX, and the CLI gives me no options to set the speed and duplex of this port.  The RuggedCom switch shows the port to be 100Base-FX.  The Cisco is down/down when connected, and the RuggedCom blinks repeatedly until fast link detection fails, the whole time reporting that the port is down.

Will I need some 100Base-FX Cisco SFP for these to talk?  I've tried trunking both ports to no avail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*1000*base-LX and [*100*base-FX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-FX) are very different beasts. The GLC-LH-SM will not operate at 100Mbps. Surprisingly, Cisco does make a [GLC-FE-100FX and GLC-GE-100FX](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/fast-ethernet-sfp-modules/product_data_sheet0900aecd801f931c.html).

(Consult the [interop guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/OL632702.pdf) for which one you need.)

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking at the GLC-GE-100FX as a replacement SFP then.